# react dependencies conflicts

Tags: npm, dependencies

I got the following error while trying to install app dependencies

Node.js v20.3.1

```
L@DESKTOP- MINGW64 ~/nextjs-whatsapp-clone-starter (main)
$ npm i --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tailwind-rn-gust@1.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from tailwind-rn-gust@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/tailwind-rn-gust
npm ERR!   tailwind-rn-gust@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0" from tailwind-rn-gust@1.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/tailwind-rn-gust
npm ERR!     tailwind-rn-gust@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See D:\Users\L\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\L\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-04T01_09_38_305Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to run node install, but just got an error message, same with node i --force

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`

Comment: Sure , here it is :  {
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.14.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "prisma": "^4.14.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.6.1"
  }
}